# Firebase Crashlytics integration not detecting or reporting crashes

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

I have integrated Crashlytics , here are the changes i have done.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self()])

        Crashlytics.sharedInstance().debugMode = true
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Did you migrate from Fabric to Firebase or are you a new Crashlytics user starting in Firebase? Let me know - Todd from Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a key like.

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run" ed9c83ee83d41dc717a07531450c480895e41264 b6cc34ec354a4f96ab160958b4s2a01cc321be62acaa6116983376a5113c9s36
```

Comment: what key is this?

Comment: @MuhammadUmar Please refer this link for getting a better idea. https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install